# Trying to make a select from db table via 2 entries - login

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

```
private bool CheckIfExist(string username, string password)
    {
         SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=  
        (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Radi\\Desktop\\
        WebSiteF86454\\WebSiteF87300\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo.TableUsers WHERE Username=@username and 
        UserPassword=@password", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adpt.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        int count = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
        if (count == 1) { return true; }
        else { return false; }; 
    }
```

Hello, I'm pretty new to sql so apologies if my question has a trivial answer.

I'm trying to make a login check via table in my database. With the code above you can see i'm checking for entries in a table based on 2 fields - username and password. I am getting an error at the SqlCommand - tells me no such table exists. For the connection string i opened server explorer -> right click on my database and copied the whole thing where it says "connection string", so i'm positive it's correct.

I have 2 tables (or at least i think so) in my database - one that stores some other content and one that stores user information. I can see the other one - called Comments, but I cannot see the table for user content (the one i need to refer to). I'll attach some screenshots to show what exactly I see.
What am I doing wrong? Am i creating the table in a wrong way? Am i refering to it in an invalid way? Any help will be appreciated, thanks. Table that i am NOT seeing or able to select is TableUsers. As you can see, i see it on the visual studio, but not in the SQL managment studio.

Agan - error is that i cannot refer to the table i need.

[image: From SQL server studio]
[image: From VisualStudio]

Comment: Your code suggests that you are using SQL Server, so I fixed the tags.

Comment: How was that DB created and how did you connected VS with your DB/DataSource? I'm asking, because your VS screenshot indicates, that you show 'all files' (toggle button at the top of your solution explorer). The files with dashed lines for icons indicate, that those files are present at your disc, but they may not be included to your project. Can your read from `Comments` table? Something is wrong with setup, not your SQL.

Comment: I do not think the connection string is opening the database you are using.  First remove the AttachDbFilename section of the connection string.  The MDF file is attached to the server and it is only needed when you are connecting to MDF tghat is not attached to the server.   When attached to server the AttachDbFilename can give error.  Second change the "Data Source" to match the server name you are seeing on the login window when you open SQL Server Management Studio.  Looks like the SQL Server is 15.0 while your connection string is not using the server.

Answer (score 0):

If it says "No such table..." then you misspelled table name. Check again. I would check list of tables with  `show tables from [database];` from code and list it in some datatable.
Still, "No such table..." says that your ConnectionString is valid.
BTW, I would suggest to you, if you only  need true/false from your query, then, you rather use `select count(*) from [table] where password=@password and user=@user`. Then, instead filling dataset/datatable, and then counting rows, rather use ExecuteScalar to store it to integer variable - it's faster and less resource hungry.